# How do you hide the sidebars in Eclipse so you can just see the code?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. One of the things I like *most* about it is the fantastic indexing, and the symbols/function outline at the right. One of the things I like *least* about it is how small the code area is due to all of the side-bars (one each in Eclipse CDT at the left, right, and bottom makes the code area quite small).

Is there a quick way to toggle between hiding and showing the sidebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering around I accidentally discovered it! **Just double-click on your open file-name tab and it will maximize to full-screen. Double-click again to toggle it back to your normal "perspective".** This applies to the left, right, and bottom sidebars too: just double-click on any of their tabs and they will maximize. Do it again to toggle back to normal size.

Comment: Even better, use a key bound to the function (maximize active view) so you don't have to take your hand off the keyboard to do this.